# How can I execute a trigger when a certain pose is detected

Tags: java, kinect

I'm currently working on an application that takes uses of the body as "controller" that taking use of a Microsoft Kinect sensor.
To get the data from the **Kinect sensor** I use **Java with Eclipse Neon** with the **J4K Java Library**.

In this project I need to find a way to let a thing happen when a certain position is taken.

I already managed to get the skeleton.

When one of [this](http://doc.aldebaran.com/2-1/family/robots/postures_robot.html) poses are taken, a trigger must happen. (Print a debug message with the name of the pose to test this). 
(when you sit or do a StandZero --> print name of that pose)

The problem I have is I can't find a way to capture the skeleton.
Ans once I captured the skeleton I don't know how to create a trigger when a certain is taken

**How can I catch a pose using J4K Libery?**
**How can I set a trigger when a certain pose is taken?**

You can find code  here:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7emFKgSQXy5cFNjZ2kwTnlIQVE

Comment: This is all about position in 3-dimensional space. How do you calculate position for each body part in a system (related or absolute)? Start from [here](http://research.dwi.ufl.edu/ufdw/j4k/Skeleton.php)

Comment: I try to calculate the positions related.
If related won't work, I will try absolute for sure.
I really need to find out how to make such a trigger.

I'm really thankful for your help.

Comment: There is a Google [Kinetic Space](https://code.google.com/archive/p/kineticspace/) program that can define/calculate the poses for u.

Comment: Are there code examples for solving this problem. The problem with this libraries is that they don't get user-friendly documentation.
I just need to find out (with code example or documentation) how I can set a trigger when a certain pose is taken.

Comment: That would be `onSkeletonFrame` event.